# My MacBook Pro is blocked

Tags: macbook-pro

I could not enter my mac, because I did not remember the password and then I changed it and tried to enter several times, but it does not let me.  I only have the close button and the password box.  I have written several times the new password and it does not take it and the other thing that I do is close the screen.  I have shutdown and restarted and nothing happens.  What can I do?  please help me :(

Comment: How did you change it if you couldn’t remember it to login to begin with?  There’s lots of details missing like which password box (FileVault or login) which version of macOS you’re using, how you set the new password etc.  please [edit] your question with the details so we can better assist.

Comment: Start at:  https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202860 @sandy